# ssl_error_bad_cert_domain when accessing site by its ip address on https

Tags: linux, ssl, ssl-certificate, https, httpd.conf

i finally got my certificate verified from a trusted CA. now, i have edited my `etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` to locate my new certificate.

i already included the ssl.conf in my `etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`.

i have setup my virtual host.

```
ServerName www.myhost.com.ph:80
NameVirtualHost *:443
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.myhost.com.ph
    DocumentRoot /home/host/public
    ServerAlias myhost.com.ph myhost.net
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

    <Directory "/home/host/public">
        AllowOverride FileInfo Limit Options Indexes
        Allow from all
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    </Directory>
    <Files ~ "^\.ht">
             Order allow,deny
             Deny from all
    </Files>
</VirtualHost>
```

and here's my ssl.conf file:

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
Listen 443
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerName www.myhost.com.ph
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/myhost.com.ph.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/www.myhost.com.ph.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/gd_bundle.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

when i access my site in a web browser via my ip address (https://125.x.xx.xxx), i still `Untrusted Connected` error. `Error code: ssl_error_bad_cert_domain`

Have I misconfigured my server setup? What are the other things I have to add/setup in my ssl and apache config? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ssl certificate is for domain name not for IP, thats why you are getting that error, your configuration looks fine.

Comment: oh. thank you for the info @Toqeer. but when i confirm the security exception on my browser, the address bar should have a lock icon but i have seen none.

Comment: Look for the log file for any error, what distro you are using? if its centos then default httpd log file in /var/log/httpd/error.log or may be /var/log/httpd/ssl_error_log.

Answer (score 2):

You need to access the https part of the site via the domain name for which you have the signed certificate, otherwise you'll always get such an error.